# Spotfire: Need to select all values in a Multi select List Box Document Property

Tags: scripting, listbox, spotfire

I have zero knowledge of coding. Can someone please help me with code.
My situation is as follows:

1. Dashboard has a Multi select List Box (Document Property). I am using that to restrict the data and calculations.
2. User does not want to select values each time. He wants a button where in (s)he click it once and all the values present in the list box gets selected.

Can someone please help me.

Regards,
Subro

Comment: @ Subro- List box has an option '(All) values' to select all values. why wasn't that used to select all values? If you could provide more details as why this button is needed that would be helpful in providing a solution.

Comment: @ksp585: Hi I am using a document Property. It populates its values from a column (unique values from a column). The only option I saw was for (none). I checked again there is no option to select all by default. Can you tell me where it is. I am using Spotfire 6.5

Comment: @ Subro- We can convert (none) option to work as 'select all'. Are you looking for only iron python script solution or any other solution with out involving scripts would also be fine?

Comment: @ksp585 Anything would be a solution for me. Mention both if it is not too much. Also if you mention script, do mention what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do. Let us say that the Document Property that the list box is used for is named "Test" and it is of type "String List". Then you can use an IronPython script like so:

```
Document.Properties["Test"] = ["First Choice","Second Choice","Third Choice"]
```

Where the string list you see above, are all the values in your list box. Make sure that the strings you assign to the document property are the ones you want to populate your list with, since sometimes the displayed values can be different than the ones assigned to the document property(The case of using the "Fixed Values" option when setting up the control).

Hope that this helps.
Zenios

Comment: Sorry for the extreme late reply. The idea had been dropped as I moved out of the project. I was bought back recently and now am asked to do the same thing. Is there a way to pull in all the values instead of typing it. The document property is loaded from a field and values go to the volume of 150. So typing them individually would be a nightmare and would require to be changed each time new values get added.